# How can I append all rows of a table to another table, including duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, append_table and source_table. I want to append all rows from source_table to append_table. This is what I have:

```sql
CREATE TABLE source_table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    val CHARACTER);

INSERT INTO source_table (id, val)
VALUES 
    (1, NULL),
    (2, 'B'),
    (4, 'B'),
    (8, 'B'),
    (9, 'B'),
    (10, NULL),
    (11, NULL);

CREATE TABLE append_table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    val CHARACTER);

INSERT INTO append_table(id, val)
VALUES 
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'A'),
    (3, NULL),
    (5, 'A'),
    (8, 'A'),
    (9, NULL),
    (10, NULL);

INSERT INTO append_table SELECT * FROM source_table
```

This gives me an error that it

> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.append_table'.

However, I do want to include the duplicate values. How can I do this?

Comment: *"However, I do want to include the duplicate values."* Then why set it as the `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @Larnu I didn't. I guess it defaulted to that? I'm new to SQL so I'm not entirely how I would change that.

Comment: *"I didn't."* Yes you did: `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` No column is defaulted to be a `PRIMARY KEY`, you have to specify it to be.

Comment: @Larnu My apologies, I see now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to declare the column as an `identity` column in `append_table`.  That lets the *database* choose the primary key.

For instance, you could calculate the maximum id in `append_table` and then add that to the ids in the source table:

```
INSERT INTO append_table (id, val)
    SELECT a.max_id + s.id, s.val
    FROM source_table s CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(id) as max_idf FROM append_table) a;
```

This changes the `id` values, of course, but the new values are inserted.